# Tailwind nested lists

Tags: css, tailwind-css

This HTML shows nested bullets as circles instead of dots. Great!

```html
<ul class="p-2 text-sm max-w-xs list-disc list-outside">
  <li class="py-2">one</li>
  
  <li class="py-2">two
    <ul class="list-disc list-outside ps-5 mt-2 space-y-1 ">
      <li>two B is nested</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  
</ul>
```

[image: bullet list]

My project uses Tailwind, though, so nested lists' bullets are all showing as dots.

How can I un-reset the Tailwind reset, but just for nested lists?

So far, I've added this SCSS, but this feels weird, *and* this doesn't fix deeper levels of nesting.

```scss
ul {
  ul {
    list-style-type: circle !important;
  }
}
```

I bet there is an official Tailwind way to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Should be `ul { ul { list-style-type: dot !important; } }` in your css rule, shouldn't it?

Comment: `list-[revert]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there is any "official Tailwind way" but here are some possible Tailwind-centric solutions.

You could use an [arbitrary variant](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/adding-custom-styles#arbitrary-variants) to select child `<ul>` elements with an [arbitrary value](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/list-style-type#arbitrary-values) to apply `list-style-type: revert`:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<ul class="pl-5 list-disc list-outside [&_ul]:list-[revert]">
  <li>one</li>

  <li>
    two
    <ul>
      <li>two B is nested</li>

      <li>
        two
        <ul>
          <li>two B is nested</li>
          <li>
            two
            <ul>
              <li>two B is nested</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could abstract these arbitrary values to be non-arbitrary:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  theme: {
    extend: {
      listStyleType: {
        revert: 'revert',
      },
    },
  },
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addVariant }) => {
      addVariant('ul', '& ul');
    }),
  ],
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<ul class="pl-5 list-disc list-outside ul:list-revert">
  <li>one</li>

  <li>
    two
    <ul>
      <li>two B is nested</li>

      <li>
        two
        <ul>
          <li>two B is nested</li>
          <li>
            two
            <ul>
              <li>two B is nested</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could write a rule in your CSS to use:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
@layer utilities {
  .nested-lists ul {
    list-style-type: revert;
  }
}
</style>

<ul class="pl-5 list-disc list-outside nested-lists">
  <li>one</li>

  <li>
    two
    <ul>
      <li>two B is nested</li>

      <li>
        two
        <ul>
          <li>two B is nested</li>
          <li>
            two
            <ul>
              <li>two B is nested</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or in a plugin:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addUtilities }) => {
      addUtilities({
        '.nested-lists ul': {
          listStyleType: 'revert',
        },
      });
    }),
  ],
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<ul class="pl-5 list-disc list-outside nested-lists">
  <li>one</li>

  <li>
    two
    <ul>
      <li>two B is nested</li>

      <li>
        two
        <ul>
          <li>two B is nested</li>
          <li>
            two
            <ul>
              <li>two B is nested</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You could have a `@layer base` style to have it applied globally via CSS:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<style type="text/tailwindcss">
@layer base {
  ul ul {
    list-style-type: revert;
  }
}
</style>

<ul class="pl-5 list-disc list-outside">
  <li>one</li>

  <li>
    two
    <ul>
      <li>two B is nested</li>

      <li>
        two
        <ul>
          <li>two B is nested</li>
          <li>
            two
            <ul>
              <li>two B is nested</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Or in a plugin:

```js
tailwind.config = {
  plugins: [
    tailwind.plugin(({ addBase }) => {
      addBase({
        'ul ul': {
          listStyleType: 'revert',
        },
      });
    }),
  ],
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com/3.4.1"></script>

<ul class="pl-5 list-disc list-outside">
  <li>one</li>

  <li>
    two
    <ul>
      <li>two B is nested</li>

      <li>
        two
        <ul>
          <li>two B is nested</li>
          <li>
            two
            <ul>
              <li>two B is nested</li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Wow, one of the most thorough, helpful answers I've seen in a long time! I used `[&_ul]:list-[revert]`. Thanks!!